# GluUnProject for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, matrix, touch, opengl-es-2.0

To detect 3D world coordinates through the 2D screen coordinates of the iOS, is there any other possible way besides the gluUnProject port?

I've been fiddling around with this days on end now, and I can't seemingly get the hang of it.

```
-(void)receivePoint:(CGPoint)loke
{

GLfloat projectionF[16];
GLfloat modelViewF[16];
GLint viewportI[4];

glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelViewF);
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionF);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewportI);

loke.y = (float) viewportI[3] - loke.y;

float nearPlanex, nearPlaney, nearPlanez, farPlanex, farPlaney, farPlanez;

gluUnProject(loke.x, loke.y, 0, modelViewF, projectionF, viewportI, &nearPlanex, &nearPlaney, &nearPlanez);
gluUnProject(loke.x, loke.y, 1, modelViewF, projectionF, viewportI, &farPlanex, &farPlaney, &farPlanez);

float rayx = farPlanex - nearPlanex;
float rayy = farPlaney - nearPlaney;
float rayz = farPlanez - nearPlanez;

float rayLength = sqrtf((rayx*rayx)+(rayy*rayy)+(rayz*rayz));

//normalizing rayVector

rayx /= rayLength;
rayy /= rayLength;
rayz /= rayLength;

float collisionPointx, collisionPointy, collisionPointz;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{
    collisionPointx = rayx * rayLength/i*50;
    collisionPointy = rayy * rayLength/i*50;
    collisionPointz = rayz * rayLength/i*50;
}
}
```

There's a good chunk of my code. Yeah, I could have easily used a struct but I was too mentally fat to do it at the time. That's something I could go back and fix later.

Anywho, the point is that when I output to the debugger using NSLog after I use gluUnProject, the nearplane's and farplane's don't relay results even close to accurate. In fact, they both relay the exact same results, not to mention, the first click always reproduces x, y, & z being all equal to "nan."

Am I skipping over something extraordinarily important here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `gluUnProject` function in ES2.0, what is this port that you are using? Also there is no `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` or `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX`, which is most likely your problem.

Comment: I know there isn't, it's some code I found online. This leaves me unsure of what to do. 

What should I use in place of `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` and `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX`?